# Help with two number theory proofs

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Stuck on these two proofs. Any help would be appreciated!

Let $a,b \in\mathbb{N}$

a) There exists a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}$ such that $a = kb + r$

b) If $a = k'b + r'$, then $k = k'$ and $r = r'$

Comment: what are your proofs so far? Also what is a continuation of a number?

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: That's precisely the content of the Division Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

For a) consider the case where $a>b$ and take the set $S=\{a-bm>0\mid m\in\Bbb N\}$. The set $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$. Then there is a minimal positive integer $r$ such that $a-bk=r$, that is 
$$a=bk+r.$$
Now, $0\le r< b$, because if $r\ge b$ then $0<r-b<r$ and 
$0<a-b(k+1)<r$. This tell us that $a-b(k+1)$ is in $S$ contradicting the minimality of $r$.

For b) we have $r-r'=b(k'-r)$ and since $r,r'<b$ then $r-r'$ is a multiple of $b$ which is less than $b$ so $b(k'-k)$ is zero which implies $k'=k$, likewise $r'=r$.